# How to train the traffic signs detector by using MATLAB's trainCascadeObjectDetector?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision

I want to detect the traffic signs using the MATLAB. I know there is a 'trainCascadeObjectDetector' function that can be used to train a detector. But the example just shows how to detect the single class- stop sign. What I want to do is try to detect more than 70 kinds of traffic signs. So I was wondering, Can I put all these kind of traffic signs as positive examples and train the detector to detect all these kinds of trafic signs?

I have a try to make all these kinds of traffic signs as positive examples and train the detectors, the stage is set 7, FalseAlarmRate as 0.2, and the number of traffic signs is about 2000, but the detector generate many false positive.

Maybe the settings is wrong, the question is, I don't know whether it is right to put all these traffic signs as positive samples and try to train one detector to detect all traffic signs. Or should I train a detector for each kind of traffic sign? I prefer the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt this will work. Traffic signs is a very broad category, in which appearance varies a lot. A stop sign has a very different appearance compared to the "one way" sign. I think the best you can do here is try to group signs by appearance. For example, you may be able to train a single detector for stop signs and "do not enter" signs.

Comment: So in this way I need to train a lot of detectors for all kinds of traffic signs....This will cause a low speed when detect the signs. Any better suggestion?

Comment: Read up on deep learning for object detection.  Here's a paper from this year's CVPR: http://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/